# How can I review all my Stop Look and Listen audits?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

As a newcomer to the review process, I think I do okay, but occasionally I'll slip up and get a "Stop Look and Listen" admonishment.  I'd like to do better.

Is there a way to review all the ones I've failed, so that perhaps I can discern a pattern?  Once the warning is issued, the question goes away, and I wonder if there's a way to see them *en masse* and hopefully improve.

Comment: I'm not sure the best way to not run into "_Stop, Look and Listen_" is to review your own reviews, but to gives enough time and reflection for each review you do.

Comment: There isn't an easy way for you to do that - no. You could click back through your review history to find them but the idea is that it's a gentle nudge and you should learn/try to find out there and then what's wrong and then move on and not let them haunt you. (It doesn't quite work if you ignore it there and then and think - "oh I know what... I supposed I'd better figure out what I did wrong - I vaguely remember a warning 3 months ago...")

Comment: If you install my [script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251508/158100) you can see how you did compared to your peers and it also indicates which reviews were audits (with an A). The script runs on the [history tab](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/history) of any review queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no easy way. You have to click through your review history and then you can see them. It's very time consuming.

[image]

To improve, I suggest read review tutorials and take more time to review each post. It's not a race for badges :)

Comment: I have a user script that runs on the history of the reviews: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/history